# What is more efficient / faster, rsync compression or ssh compression?

Tags: ssh, rsync, compression

I currently rsync files:
(i) locally and
(ii) remotely over WAN (connection c. 8mbps down / 1.5mbps up).

I am considering adding to rsync:

> -z

to compress files.

Or alternatively adding to ssh:

> -C

Which one is better and in fact, is there any large benefit at all?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Based off the [rsync manual](http://rsync.samba.org/ftp/rsync/rsync.html), it is better to compress with rsync -z

> Note that this option typically achieves **better compression ratios than can be achieved by using a compressing remote shell or a compressing transport** because it takes advantage of the implicit information in the matching data blocks that are not explicitly sent over the connection.

Comment: Thank you. If I'm compressing in rsync do I need to switch off ssh compression, so "-o Compression=no"? Or can I leave ssh as is?

Comment: Yes, turn ssh compression off. The data is already compressed, no need to try to compress it again.

Answer (score 3):

In most cases, `rsync -z` compression will suit your need.
However, the `rsync -z` compression does not compress metadata exchanged prior to the file copy (notably files list).
In order to also compress the files list, I would recommend to also use the `ssh -C` option. Especially when you have both:

- a large number of files to transfer
- few changes between your source and destination files

Answer (score -3):

You seem to be confusing compression with encryption. SSH doesn't compress by default. No need to turn it off since it isn't being used by default. You can use rsync's compression to reduce the amount of data sent via SSH - but SSH's speed is far more impacted by the encryption of everything that goes through it rather than saving app. 15% by compressing the source data. If you change what SSH uses for encryption, to use a weaker cipher (e.g. arcfour), or if you patch it to allow turning encryption off completely (INsecure shell), then SSH will complete the transfer in far less time.

Comment: - Regarding *SSH compression* :
Lots of people (and I really mean a lot) tend to put `Comprssion yes` in their *.ssh/config* files to improve data rate on slower links (when remoting over DSL or 3/4G, etc.)
`-oCompression=no` is necessary in those configurations.

 - Regarding *encryption* : *Blowfish* is another possible (use: `-c blowfish-cbc`). It's theoretically weaker than AES256. But unlike RC4 it still hasn't known cryptanalytic weakness (though nowaday, nobody is actively looking at it) and is much faster on architectures lacking AES256 hardware acceleration.